# Word "complements" tab?

Tags: vba, ms-word

For a friend, I've to fastly push macros in a new documents with new styles.

I moved the macro, it works fine. But, on the old document I've a ribbon named "Complements" which contains a shortcut to my macro. On the new document, no way to get those.

How to get this "Complements" ribbon's displayed? It seems it's a base ribbon from MS.

Comment: I don't see a question here. If you need help with something, try to be clear about what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, I added more details about the question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to allow a user of the new document to execute the macro would be to create a control and add it to Word's Quick Access Toolbar (QAT). Greg Maxey has a quick tutorial here (the information you want begins on step four of these instructions):

[Add a Macro to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Add_Macro_To_QAT.htm)

And there is some additional information on this process for both Word 2007 and Word 2010 that can be found here:

[Adding Commands to the Quick Access Toolbar](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/adding_commands_to_the_quick_access_toolbar.html)

Alternatively, and with greater effort, if the Complements tab you describe is a custom XML Ribbon tab, the entire Complements Ribbon tab can be moved into the new document. The .docm or .dotm file that contains the original macro is actually a renamed .zip file that contains within it a file named customUI.xml (Word 2007) or customUI14.xml (Word 2010). This contents of this file, which defines the layout, look, and functions of a document's customized Ribbon, can be brought over to the new file, provided the effort is put into learning a bit about RibbonX (Ribbon XML). An excellent reference for this is:

[RibbonX: Customizing the Office 2007 Ribbon](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470191112.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the "complement" ribbon is a MS Word standard ribbon, not something I can create(as well as the developer ribbon). I can see it in the option, but I can't activate it.

I saw the QAT, but I can't use it, I need to replace this tools at the same place it was. :(

Comment: @J4N, Microsoft does not include a "Complements" tab in the Word 2010 or 2007 ribbons. You can confirm this on another computer with a fresh (no add-ins) install of Word. The tab you refer to is either a custom made ribbon tab or was installed by a third-party software add-in (also custom-made). If you wish to put in the time (and it will take a bit), you can learn to create custom tabs or, if your "Complements" tab is not the result of a third-party add-in, you can transfer the code to recreate the tab in another document. The RibbonX document I reference above will help you with either task.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just noticed that it isn't called like this in office 2010 English, it's called "Add-in" ribbon bar

Comment: @J4N, "Add-Ins" is a contextual ribbon tab that only appears when a pre-ribbon Word document or template containing custom toolbars or menus is opened in or converted to a Word 2007/2010 document or template. The Add-Ins tab displays the custom commands from Word 2003 and before as controls within the ribbon interface. The only way to recreate an Add-Ins tab in your new document would be to find the original .doc/.dot file that contains the toolbar/macros needed and convert it. Lacking that you will need to call your ribbon tab another name and use the methods I reference in my answer above.

Comment: Okay, I took the old document, put all my new data into it, and I have still have it. Thank you!